# Android sending data to Arduino via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino-uno

Using various tutorials, I have managed to connect my Android phone to a HC-05 bluetooth module connected to an Arduino. What I'm trying to do is have 5 Buttons set up that will transmit a unique integer per button only when the button is held down, otherwise they will send a "0" when the button is released. ergo BUTTON1 sends a "1" when pressed and "0" when released, BUTTON2 sens a "2" when pressed and a "0" when released. Currently, I cannot figure out how to send ANY data over the connection. From reading and watching various tutorials I've gained a small understanding but seem to be missing something.

Towards the bottom of my code in the public void run(), i have set up an OnClickListener for one of my buttons to try to send...well something once its pressed just to see if I can send SOMETHING useful to the Arduino.

Here is where I have my OnClickListener. I believe I should be sending "T" to the Arduino.

```
pUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String testr="T:";
                        byte[] msgBuffer = testr.getBytes();
                        try {

                            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Rather than dumping your entire activity can you narrow down the code in your question to a smaller example?

Comment: Sorry about that. I tend to learn best by seeing everything as opposed to small snippets as theres usually some small piece of relevant information in some other part. I narrowed down the code to the OnClick listener in question.

Answer (score 2):

**First**

Basically as per your requirement you can not use onClickListner instead use onTouchListner

**Example**

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       //send integer value here.(pressed)
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       //Send zero here.(released)
    }
 }
};
```

here is a sample code for sending and receiving data from bluetoothSPP

this method is to connect bluetooth device to remote device

```
private void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice mBTDevice) {
    try {
        SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

        mBtSocket = mBTDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
        mBtSocket.connect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("connectBT", "while connecting device");
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

use this for sending bytes.

```
public void send(String data) {

    byte[] buffer = data.getBytes();
    try {
        mOutputStream = mBtSocket.getOutputStream();
        mOutputStream.write(buffer);
        Log.d("message", data + " sent");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

use this function for sending Integers

```
 public void send() {

    byte[] buffer = new bytes[size];
           buffer[0]=(byte)'1';//prepare data like this
           ..
           ..
    try {
        mOutputStream = mBtSocket.getOutputStream();
        mOutputStream.write(buffer);
        Log.d("message", " sent");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)